# ¿Por que me quitaron la posibilidad de hacer preguntas en mi cuenta de stackoverflow en español?

Tags: soporte

En mi cuenta de stack overflow en español me quitaro la posibilidad de formular preguntas porque dice que mis preguntas no tienen la calidad requerida y lo unico que tengo es una pregunta con valoracion negativa de -5 que me elimino la comunidad. No creo que sea justo que por una pregunta con valoracion negativa me quiten esa posibilidad y me dicen que mis contribuciones no estan haciendo mejor al sitio, cuando tengo 5 respuestas realizadas y unas de ellas esta aceptada, si alguien pudiese decirme si hay posibilidad de recuperar la formulacion de preguntas desde mi cuenta y que debo hacer, me ayudaria mucho.

Comment: Cuento 6 preguntas actualmente no borradas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/110531/yoelvis-socas-brito?tab=questions. ¿Borraste otras? ¿Intentaste mejorar las existentes? El algorimo para respuestas es independiente del de preguntas.

Comment: Si he borrado como 2 por recomendación, y he editado las existentes para acercarme lo mas posible a lo que se exije.

Comment: Lo que te explica gbianchi es correcto. Una cosa que puedes hacer para que el bloqueo se levante más rápido es editar alguna de las preguntas eliminadas para que se ajusten mejor al formato del sitio (añadiendo el código intentado, explicando con qué dificultades te estás encontrando, o incluso respondiéndolas si encontraste la solución). A veces sólo con recibir un +1 se levanta el bloqueo.

Answer (score 2):

Estas bloqueado para preguntar, mas no para editar o realizar respuestas. El sistema toma en cuenta todas las preguntas que hiciste durante toda tu historia, y te bloquea para hacer preguntas por las preguntas que hiciste.

Estos bloqueos son temporales y se levantan solos. Los moderadores no podemos saber por cuánto tiempo se te bloqueó.

Lo que sí se ve, es que tienes 5 preguntas eliminadas, solo 3 con respuesta aceptadas, y solo dos con votos a favor.

Todo esto, más tu última pregunta, llevó al sistema a considerar que debías tomar aire y respirar antes de hacer tu próxima pregunta.

¿[Has leído sobre cómo elaborar buenas preguntas](/help/how-to-ask)? ¿[Te tomas el tiempo para hacerlas y reflexionar al respecto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? Desgraciadamente, en este caso, ni siquiera los moderadores podemos hacer algo.